# C is stuck in a infinite loop

Tags: c, loops, terminal

I have this simple program I want to test myself and it basically reads from terminal characters and counts how many lower case characters have been entered.

In the function I've called to do this it seems it just runs on forever in a loop.

```
/*
Create a function that reads the number of lower case letters from the user
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void CopyMe(char []);

main ()
{
    char letters [100];
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        letters [i++] = getchar();
    }
    while (letters [i-1] != '\n');
    letters [i-1] = '\0';

    CopyMe(letters);

    printf("Done \n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void CopyMe(char a[])
{
    int lowercase = 0;
    int i=0;
    while ( a[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (a[i] >= 'a' && a[i] <= 'z')
        {
            lowercase++;
        }
    }
    printf("Lowercase: %d \n", lowercase);
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the loop. The reason should quickly become clear.

Comment: You can't go wrong with `for (i=0; i<MAX; i++) { .. }`.

Comment: Anytime a loop seems to "run forever" you might do well to check the condition of the loop and determine if anything within the loop body will ever change it.

Comment: My guess is here : `while (letters [i-1] != '\n');`

Comment: `while` I sometimes use a `while` loop, my co-workers (and myself, `for` that matter) find a `for` loop much more easy to read, maintain, understand and, as a construct, a better tool `for` avoiding stupid mistakes... use `for(i=0;a[i] != '\0';++i)` or, if you insist, why not increment the pointer `a++`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never increment `i` in your `CopyMe` function, so the while loop never terminates, always working on `a[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to increment i variable...

Comment: in CopyMe… Just use for loops ffs

Answer (score 1):

You aren't incrementing `i` in `CopyMe`:

```
void CopyMe(char a[])
{
    int lowercase = 0;
    int i=0;
    while ( a[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (a[i] >= 'a' && a[i] <= 'z')
        {
            lowercase++;
        }
        i++; // <------- Don't forget about meeeeeee!!!
    }
    printf("Lowercase: %d \n", lowercase);
}
```